# React Redux: Where to do heavy the heavy lifting? Reducer or ActionCreator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

It's been asked before, but my scenario is different:

I am pulling images off a server, which I'm doing in an action creator:

```
export function getResults(settings,page){
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(startGettingResults());

        return Axios.get('http://localhost:8080/getimages/',{params:{settings: settings,page:page}}).then(function(response){
            return dispatch(resultsSuccess(response.data.results, page));
        }).catch(function(){
            return dispatch(resultsFailure());
        });
    }
}
```

This is quite simple & straightforward: I'm doing API calls in the action creator and storing everything in state via my reducer.

However, when the user clicks a certain element on my site, I want all the current images in the store to change color. I'm going to do the color change on the client app rather than the server.

My question is now, where do I best do this heavy lifting?

- In the reducer, which can easily access the images in the current state?
- In an actioncreator? The problem here is that I'd have to pass along all images from the store, which means I would have to load them as props on my component.

I'm a bit lost on the best approach to handle this. Where do you put your heavy lifting and data manipulation functions?

Comment: It makes sense to do it inside the reducer as it has access to the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a new action, for example 'COLOUR_ALL_IMAGES' and dispatch that? The reducer will understand the state and 'know' about all te images, no need to pass them as part of the action?

Comment: And then do the heavy lifting in the reducer?

Comment: I guess so, depends what you mean by heavy lifting. If the colour change is to be achieved via styling then there's not much 'heavy lifting' to do and the reducer is taking an action and changing the state. If there are actual side effects then the reducer is NOT the place to do this, as it's meant to be a pure function (in functional terms) and therefore have no side effects (should operate only on the state).

Comment: It's heavy lifting: I'm grayscaling the image via javascript and then colorizing it via javascript. That's what I was also thinking: it's not the place to do this in the reducer, but I'm unsure of where I would best do it. Actions seem the best place, but it seems stupid to have to pass all store images to an action just to make it do the work.  Guess there's no other way..

Comment: Ah, I understand. Yes, it shouldn't be the reducer as that would be introducing side effects. Does it need to be in actions though, what about just plain old javascript and dispatch an action once completed? It depends whether you want your state to reflect (say) colorization has started, and subsequently ended.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an action. But the problem I'm having is this: I have 2 smart components. One to show all images on screen, and one sidebar with settings where the user can select a color. If a color is selected, the colorization process should start. For that though, I'd need to let my 'results' component know that it can start coloring results. With plain JS, I would just fire an event from the sidebar and the main component would pick it up. However, I can't really listen to dispatches outside of a component, or can I? I'm new to react and am not seeing it for this scenario

Comment: All of your components are subscribed to the store, so (for example) if a colour is selected an action can be dispatched and the store updated (the new state could reflect the colour chosen and that the current state was 'colorization in progress'). As the second component subscribes to changes in the state it could then start the colorization process, dispatching an action (colorization complete) when finished (possibly other actions for 'cancelled' and 'errors').

Comment: Where would I best listen for these changes? As I'm using redux, I can't use 'subscribe' directly. Would I listen for changes in MapStateToProps?

Comment: Yes, that will link state to your components' props.

Comment: Many thanks - also consider componentWillReceiveProps, which will fire when the component's props change in response to the state change. Best of luck with everything.